# Установка PECL-расширения на PHP 7.3

Tags: php, pecl

Скачиваю библиотеку bbcode здесь: https://pecl.php.net/package/bbcode/1.0.3b1/windows (5.6 Thread Safe (TS) x64). Копирую из архива файлы .dll и .pdb в W:\modules\php\PHP_7.3-x64\ext и в C:\php7\ext. В файле php.ini пишу extension  = bbcode. Но почему локальный сервер не видит эту библиотеку? Что мне ещё нужно сделать или указать?

В логах - сообщение:

> [25-May-2020 08:39:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'bbcode' (tried: w:/modules/php/PHP_7.3-x64/ext\bbcode (Не найден указанный модуль.), w:/modules/php/PHP_7.3-x64/ext\php_bbcode.dll (%1 не является приложением Win32.)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Скачиваю библиотеку для php 5.6. Устанавливаю на php 7.3 и удивляюсь тому что не работает. Странно, да?

Comment: @ArchDemon но там максимальная версия 5.6

Comment: вот именно. данное расширение больше не поддерживается.